# Why does an unfloated div cover/overlap a floated div? (with "why" being the focus)

Tags: css, css-float

My question relates to when you have one div floated (float:left) and a div right afterwards that is not floated. In that situation, **why** does the unfloated div cover and overlap the first div?  It's like the first, floated div is taken out of the flow (like absolute positioning) in how the 2nd unfloated div goes over the 1st div.

I am aware that text in the 2nd unfloated div does not do this.  It seems aware of the first div and floats next to it.

I am also aware that the fix is to have the 2nd div also floated to the left.

My question is a focus on the **why**.  Why does the 2nd unfloated div (except for any text that might be in it) cover and overlap the 1st floated div?

In another similar question here on Stack Overflow, someone said "float removes an element from the normal flow, meaning that neighboring elements are positioned as if the float didn't exist...This isn't the case if an element has an inline display."  So my question is **why** is a floated element removed from the normal flow (except for inline elements)?  I understand why that is the case with inline elements (you want the text flushed to the floated div for word wrap around an image, for example).  But why is it removed from the normal flow at all???

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean.

```css
.box1 {
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: blue solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think the second div is covering the floated div? Did you give the floated div a background color?

Comment: Why? Because that's how the float behavior is defined. If it wasn't removed from normal flow, it couldn't achieve it's purpose, which is to position itself on the left or right side of it's container. Other elements, if any, would get in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's like the first, floated div is taken out of the flow

Exactly, that's the reason. Floated elements are [out-of-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23):

> An element is called out of flow if it is floated, absolutely
>   positioned, or is the root element.

And that's necessary given the behavior of [floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line.

If they were not removed from the normal flow, they would continue occupying some space in their initial position before being shifted.

Note inline floats are not an exception, because there is no such thing. Floats are blockified as explained in [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Therefore, blocks following a float overlap it:

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

You can prevent this behavior by establishing a new block formatting context:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new [block formatting
>   context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible')
>   must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block
>   formatting context as the element itself. If necessary,
>   implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any
>   preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is
>   sufficient space.

```css
.box1 {
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border: blue solid 3px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish BFC */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```